# How do I apply a single iteration of Floyd's algorithm to an adjacency matrix?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, shortest-path

I have the following adjacency matrix for a graph with nodes {a,b,c,d}:

\begin{bmatrix}
 &  &  a&  b&  c& d\\ 
 &  &  &  &  & \\ 
 a&  &  0&  1&  100& 10\\ 
 b&  &  13&  0&  2& 100\\ 
 c&  &  100&  12&  0& 3\\ 
 d&  &  4&  100&  11& 0
\end{bmatrix}
I want to apply the Warshall-Floyd algorithm. I can do this since I know it computes the shortest paths between each pair of nodes. By manually calculating each individual entry, I get the final matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
 &  &  a&  b&  c& d\\ 
 &  &  &  &  & \\ 
 a&  &  0&  1&  3& 6\\ 
 b&  &  9&  0&  2& 5\\ 
 c&  &  7&  8&  0& 3\\ 
 d&  &  4&  5&  7& 0
\end{bmatrix}

My question is this: how can I draw the matrix after each 'iteration' of the algorithm? What qualifies as a single iteration and what does the matrix look like after iteration 1?

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you find the pseudocode for Floyd-Warshall?  Did you try running the pseudocode by hand?  Is there something specific you are confused about?